# Download link redirects to login page from firefox

Tags: http, download, http-redirect, download-manager

I'm developing a download manager application and I came across a weird issue in regard to google drive download links. Take [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GppfSkq8gNG_kC4NVLK6qM4MRJ7k60CO/view) for example. On Firefox, when I click the download button and let Firefox start the download then stop it and copy the download url from the download item and send a head request to that url, it gets redirected to a google html login page and cannot download a file because of it. However, When I do the same thing on google chrome (retrieving the download url from chrome and sending a head request), the download link works just fine. This is a very weird edge-case I came across and couldn't able to figure out the reason for.
If I add the same link that was retrieved from Firefox to IDM, by jumping back and forth between redirects, IDM is able to get the file information and download it and I have no idea how this works.

If anyone could even point me to the right direction I would appreciate it.
Thank you